# Windows app to monitor Linux server load, etc of a remote server in real time?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, monitoring

Is there a desktop app (for Windows preferably) that will connect to a remote Linux server, and provide a realtime meter/history graph of the server load and other metrics on that remote server?  Often times there is a server performance issue that I only hear about after the fact, and it would be great to have an app that continually monitors a server and can alert me if server load gets too high.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look to [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) . It runs on Windows and you need to enable SNMP in your linux box.

Comment: Yes, PRTG can do this. The latest version (7.2, currently in beta) includes a nice Windows GUI, too.

Answer (score 4):

If you have deep pockets, [HP Open View](http://openview.hp.com) can run on windows.

After you have a heart attack at the price, you should consider [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org).

It will run on linux & you can run it as an appliance & access everything you need via a browser.

Comment: Nice humor though.

Answer (score 3):

I have two suggestions.  The first would be to install Munin and Monit.  These will both run on your linux box.  This ensures you can get trending and alerting even if your windows box is offline.  They are both Open source.  Here is an decent writeup on setting them up.  http://howtoforge.com/server-monitoring-with-munin-and-monit-on-centos-5.2  Make sure to secure the access to those tools by source IP address to ensure the entire world can't see your system performance or identify ways to attack you.

Second I would suggest looking at Hyperic http://www.hyperic.org.  They have a nice tool that you can easily get up and running on windows.  I will caution that it does use an agent that you will need to install on your linux box.  The nice part about that is you can maintain trending data at the client while performing maintenance at your monitoring server.  The open source Hyperic project is more than sufficient for monitoring a single server or scale to 20-30 servers.  If you start to manage more than just a few servers I would suggest looking into purchasing the commercial version.  There are many tools that will meet your needs just do your homework.  Monitoring tools are something that you want to get right the first time as most if not all do not have portable data that you can move to another monitoring system.

The last thing you should look into is log aggregation and searching.  There isn't really a tool out there that does this better than Splunk http://www.splunk.com.  Again they have a free version that will meet your basic needs but as they grow you can move to a commercial version.

Comment: +1 perfect, munin was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gkrellm](http://members.dslextreme.com/users/billw/gkrellm/gkrellm.html) for live monitoring.
For a long term monitoring and history I use [NetMRG](http://www.netmrg.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring networks is a task of each sysadmin, and there are many solutions.
If you look for free solution please take a look to [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) and [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) or [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use RRDTOOL

Answer (score 0):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is fairly trivial to configure to email you on resource triggers (memory, cpu usage, etc).   Even with another solution in place -- monit is a wonderful 'backup' that can email you when issues arrise -- or even be configured to resolve them itself (restart Apache on high memory usage due to a leak in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a windows tool, but it can certainly be used from windows: http://www.cacti.net/