# What is the best way to monitor a production server?

Tags: mysql, apache-2.2, monitoring, monit

We are running two production servers with Apache 2 and MySQL. I am looking for a reliable way of monitoring our load, stability and uptime.

I have come across [monit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monit), but are there better alternatives?

Comment: Depending where you'll be doing your monitoring from, but there's a post about monitoring that might help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/54603/windows-app-to-monitor-linux-server-load-etc-of-a-remote-server-in-real-time

Answer (score 10):

I configured [Zabbix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabbix) on a virtual machine at [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) and have been quite pleased with the solution.  Since it's physically separate from our production servers it will alert me even if the production network has issues.  The virtual machine at Slicehost is cheap and easy to backup.

[Zabbix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabbix) is great because it can monitor website response time and also CPU, disk, and just about anything else.  Zabbix will store historical data so you can see how statistics trend over time.  I also prefer Zabbix over [Nagios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) because Zabbix has a powerful web based configuration interface.

Comment: +1 for Zabbix. Simple Flexible and very scalable solution.

Answer (score 7):

I personally use Munin for resource and metric reporting. It has plugins for many applications/metrics already, and is ridiculously easy to write plugins for.

For availability monitoring/alerting I've used Zabbix, Zennos, Nagios, and Hyperic. Of all of those, I liked Zabbix the best.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a free monitoring solution like [Incinga](http://www.icinga.org/) or [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). There are tons of plugins for every check you can think of. Or you could just write your own script which reports a status ("good", "bad", whatever...). A good commercial thingy would be [WhatsUp Gold](http://www.whatsupgold.com/). It includes performance measurement tools, too.

If you want some real gold, take a look at [Jazzey](http://www.jazzey.com/). It's a real high class, really expencive, end-to-end monitoring tool. It simulates real users working with your (web-) apps. Spent lots of ours with at work.

Answer (score 2):

Monit works locally on the servers, so it doesn't really give you realistic stability statistics. If the network your server on goes out, or the server itself goes down, monit can not notify you.

I use [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) for load, stability and uptime monitoring; it does just about anything you can think of. The only downside is that you need to have it running on an external server.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is a good place to start.  If you also would like to track trends with the server performance and graph them I recommend looking at Cacti as well.

http://www.cacti.net/