# Server monitoring service

Tags: monitoring

Is there a service that can monitor my web server and annoy me with phone calls (and or email) when it detects that its unresponsive to HTTP requests?

Comment: Have a look at this serverfault question: "[Can anyone recommend a website monitoring service?](http://serverfault.com/questions/1014/can-anyone-recommend-a-website-monitoring-service)" Or, do it yourself: "[What is the best way to monitor a production server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/71441/what-is-the-best-way-to-monitor-a-production-server/72731#72731)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) has been working pretty well for me for a month.  I only have a few sites in it, but it's noticed every time I've restarted the apache server :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft System Center or you can setup Opmanager. Both work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [ServerGuard24](http://www.serverguard24.de/index.html) for > 3 years and am very happy. They send emails and sms and are quite cheap.

Answer (score 0):

There's a blue zillion of them. Here's another one:

http://www.mon.itor.us/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://100pulse.com to monitor your website. They send email, sms, rss feed alert, gadget, twitter direct message alerts and more features